Link assets from multiple blend files in a folder with a script
Is it possible to select a folder with subfolders containing blend files with a script to search all blend files for assets and link to the current blend file?
So far I have only been able to set this for a single blend file, but not for a folder.
                    # path to the blend
                    filepath = "C:\\Test\\Library\\AreaShapes.blend"
                    # name of collection(s) to append or link
                    coll_name = "TestCollection" 
                    link = True
                    data_to.collections = [c for c in data_from.collections if c.startswith(coll_name)]



Get all blend from a specific folder

from pathlib import Path

def get_glob_files(folder, suffix, recursive=True):
    s = f'**/*{suffix}'  if recursive else f'*{suffix}'
    return [str(fp) for fp in Path(folder).glob(s) if fp.is_file()]

# test
folder_path = "D:\\Folder name"
print(get_glob_files(folder_path, '.blend'))


Link assets

How can I append an object from an external blender file using a relative path with Python?

Interface


import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty

from pathlib import Path

def get_glob_files(folder, suffix, recursive=True):
    s = f'**/*{suffix}'  if recursive else f'*{suffix}'
    return [str(fp) for fp in Path(folder).glob(s) if fp.is_file()]


class ScanFolder(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.scan_folder"
    bl_label = "Accept"

    directory: StringProperty(name="Directory", description="Folder Directory")
    filter_folder: BoolProperty(default=True, options={"HIDDEN"})

    def execute(self, context):
        print("-- end --")
        print(self.directory)
        
        for blend in get_glob_files(self.directory, '.blend'):
            print(blend)
            # Do what you want.

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(ScanFolder)

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.scan_folder("INVOKE_DEFAULT")

